# Как отобразить массив с данными в обратном порядке

Tags: массивы, php

PHP как отобразить массив в обратном порядке.
Например есть

```
$mass[] = "a";
$mass[] = "b";
$mass[] = "c";
$mass[] = "d";
$mass[] = "e";
```

Мне нужно вывести так e,d,c,b,a.

PS! массив не определенной длинны

Answer (score 6):

[array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reverse.php)

> array_reverse — Возвращает массив с элементами в обратном порядке

Answer (score 2):

Вам подойдут две функции, которые очень похожи:

```
1) rsort($mass);
2) $mass = array_reverse($mass);
```